# Adding Linux utilities to docker image based on busybox

Tags: docker, dockerfile, busybox

When I try `df -h` for busybox container I get the following results:

```
$ docker run -it busybox du -h  
# expected results
```

What I need is the output of `df -b` which gives me the following:

```
$ docker run -it busybox du -b                                                                     
du: invalid option -- b
BusyBox v1.30.0 (2018-12-31 18:16:17 UTC) multi-call binary.

Usage: du [-aHLdclsxhmk] [FILE]...

Summarize disk space used for each FILE and/or directory

    -a  Show file sizes too
    -L  Follow all symlinks
    -H  Follow symlinks on command line
    -d N    Limit output to directories (and files with -a) of depth < N
    -c  Show grand total
    -l  Count sizes many times if hard linked
    -s  Display only a total for each argument
    -x  Skip directories on different filesystems
    -h  Sizes in human readable format (e.g., 1K 243M 2G)
    -m  Sizes in megabytes
    -k  Sizes in kilobytes (default)
```

As many of the standard utilites are trimmed in busybox image or non-existent, the behaviour is not surprising. As dockerhub's busybox page [suggests](https://hub.docker.com/_/busybox):

> ```
> FROM busybox
> COPY ./my-static-binary /my-static-binary
> CMD ["/my-static-binary"]
> ```

So, I created a Dockerfile with the following content trying to copy my Ubuntu 16.04 `du` binary to the image:

```
FROM busybox
COPY /usr/bin/du /bin/du
CMD ["/bin/du", "-b"]
```

But when I try `docker build` I get the following error:

```
$ docker build .              
Sending build context to Docker daemon  2.048kB
Step 1/3 : FROM busybox
 ---> 3a093384ac30
Step 2/3 : COPY /usr/bin/du /bin/du
COPY failed: stat /var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-builder362173879/usr/bin/du: no such file or directory
```

I don't know if it's the right way of adding utilities to such minimal images, but I would appreciate if you let me know the ways that utilities such as (complete) `du`, `curl`, etc. could be added given that there is no package manager like `apt`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the just-Busybox Docker base image isn't meeting your needs, you can change your Dockerfile to be based on a more full-featured Linux distribution.  `FROM ubuntu` is very common and includes the GNU versions of the Unix toolset (and their assorted vendor extensions); `FROM alpine` is also common and is based around Busybox plus a minimal package manager.

Another good answer is to limit yourself to the functionality defined in [POSIX.1](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/): [du(1) is not required to support a -b option](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/du.html#tag_20_36).  This will help if you're trying to write Alpine-based images or run on systems that aren't Linux (MacOS being the most prominent present-day example).

You probably will not succeed in copying individual binaries from your host system into a Docker image, path issues aside, because the library environments are likely to be very different.  If you run `ldd $(which du)` on the host, all of the libraries listed there need to be present in the image and at a similar version.  The `busybox` base image probably doesn't even include a `libc.so.6`, which is a minimum requirement for most dynamically-linked binaries.

The correct answer to your question as it's written is to write a multi-stage Dockerfile that has a first stage with a full C toolchain that builds a static version of [GNU Coreutils](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/), and then a second stage that copies it in.  That's a lot of work for a tool that's probably not part of the core application you actually want to run.

Comment: Thank you very much David. I really appreciate your detailed answer. My question was a simplified. The main problem was to use `du -b` in a container based on a derived image whose parent was some flavour of busybox. For tackling this I will use `du -k` and convert it to bytes by multiplication. I was curious about how to solve it in general and your answer was really enlightening.

Comment: Also consider using language-native tools (_e.g._, Python's `os.walk`), or, if your application really is a shell-script-oriented application to do some sort of filesystem management, just running it on the host (and avoiding filesystem mapping and permission issues).

Answer (score 1):

The `COPY` is not working because of following restriction:

> COPY obeys the following rules:
>
> The  path must be inside the context of the build; you cannot COPY ../something /something, because the first step of a docker build
>   is to send the context directory (and subdirectories) to the docker
>   daemon.

You can read more in [Dockerfile documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#copy).

In order to make your busybox image work you should do following:

1. copy `du` to directory where your `Dockerfile` resides: `cp /usr/bin/du .`
2. update your `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM busybox
COPY du /du
CMD ["du", "-b"]
```

3. rebuild your image: `docker build .`

According to busybox docker [documentation](https://hub.docker.com/_/busybox) you should put copied binaries directly to the `/` instead of `/bin/`.

Comment: Thanks. It solved the problem but I get `standard_init_linux.go:195: exec user process caused "no such file or directory"` when running the container. Maybe a problem of dependencies now?

Comment: try run following: `docker build -t mybusybox:1.0 .` and then `docker run -it --rm mybusybox:1.0` does it give you the same errror?

Comment: I tried copying it to `/bin/du` to replace it with the original `du` to no avail. Even with `COPY du /du` that you specified, when I inspect the container with `docker run -it mybusybox:2 sh` and try `./du` although I can see it in the results of `ls`, I get `sh: ./du: not found`

Comment: so you copied the `du` to `/` (not the `/bin/du`), within the container `ls /` shows you the `du` but if you execute `du` (not `./du`) the file is not found, right?

Comment: When I execute `du` in a container which `du` is copied to its root (`/`), it uses the default `du` in `/bin/du` that does not have `-b`. When I copy `du` to `/bin/du` (replacing the image's original `du`), it causes the error I mentioned in the first comment. The not found error happens if I run `./du` in case it is copied in `/` and I try to run it when my current directory is `/`.